# Nesesito ayuda ordenado alfabéticamente

Tags: php, array, bucle-for

Estoy intentando de ordenar de forma alfabética un `array` pero no lo he logrado.

Mi `script` completo

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['nom'])){
  $nom = ($_POST['nom']);
 }
 if(isset($_POST['btn_user'])){
    for ($i=0; $i < 6; $i++) { 
      echo "orden por el usuario:";
      echo  $nom[$i]."<br>";
    }
 } elseif (isset($_POST['btn_inverso'])) {
    echo "ORDEN INVERSO<br>";
    for ($p=0; $p < 6; $p++) {
      $j=5-$p;
      echo $nom[$j]."<br>"; 
    }    
 } elseif (isset($_POST['btn_desc'])) {
    echo "ALFABETICAMENTE<br>";
    for ($x=0; $x < 6; $x++) {
      $a=5-$x;
      echo $nom[$a]."<br>";
    }
 }
?>

<form name="frmData" method="post"><br>
  <input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['nom'])){echo $nom[0];}?>" name="nom[]"> <br>
  <input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['nom'])){echo $nom[1];}?>" name="nom[]"> <br>
  <input type="text"  value="<?php if(isset($_POST['nom'])){echo $nom[2];}?>"name="nom[]"> <br>
  <input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['nom'])){echo $nom[3];}?>" name="nom[]"> <br>
  <input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['nom'])){echo $nom[4];}?>" name="nom[]"> <br>
  <input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['nom'])){echo $nom[5];}?>" name="nom[]"> <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="btn_user" value="orden por el user"> <br>
  <input type="submit" name="btn_inverso" value="orden inverso"> <br>
  <input type="submit" name="btn_desc" value="orden alfabéticamente"> <br>
</form>
```

Comment: Puedes lograrlo utilizando las funciones de ordenados: [http://php.net/manual/es/array.sorting.php](http://php.net/manual/es/array.sorting.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ordenar alfabéticamente en `php` puedes usar:

```
sort($nom); // orden ascendente

rsort($nom); // orden descendente
```

Y luego recorres el array ya ordenado

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($nom); $i++){
   echo $nom[$i];
}
```